# Is it possible to get the headers of a request using Ruby's HTTPClient gem before the request completes?

Tags: ruby, httpclient, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a requirement to proxy a request in a Rails app. I was hoping I could proxy it with chunking (so, 1 chunk received, one chunk is sent). The app is working fine *without* chunking (load the request into memory, and transmit).

Here is my code to proxy the chunks through to the end-client:

```
self.response.headers['Last-Modified'] = Time.now.ctime.to_s
self.response_body = Enumerator.new do |y|
  client = HTTPClient.new
  http_response = client.get(proxy_url, nil, headers) do |chunk|
    y << chunk
  end
end
```

The problem is, I can't inspect "http_response" until all the chunks have been received, thus I can't set the headers based on the headers of the client.

What I'm trying to do is transmit the headers returned from the client *before* the first chunk is sent.  Is this possible?

If not, is this pattern possible in any other Ruby HTTP client gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I have a solution for you.

If you call `get_async` instead, it will retun immediately with an `HTTPClient::Connection` object that is updated with the header information as soon as it is received. This code sample demonstrates.

The patch to `HTTPClient::Connection` is almost certainly not necessary for you, but it lets you write things like `conn.queue.size?` and `conn.queue.empty?`.

`conn.pop` *blocks* until the response (or exception) has been pushed to the queue by the async thread and then returns the normal `HTTP::Message` object. (Note that, if you are using the monkey patch, you can use `conn.queue.empty?` to see if `pop` is going to block.)

`resp.content` returns an `IO` object which is a pipe read endpoint, and can be called as soon as `pop` hs returned. The other end is written by the async thread as the data arrives, and you can read the entire content in one go or in whatever size chunks you like using `read`.

```
require 'httpclient'

class HTTPClient::Connection
  attr_reader :queue
end

client = HTTPClient.new

conn = client.get_async 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)'

resp = conn.pop
resp.header.all.each { |name, val| puts "#{name}=#{val}" }
puts
pipe = resp.content
while chunk = pipe.read(8192)
  print chunk
end
```

---

<strike>You *could* parse the first chunk you receive to extract the headers</strike>, but I suggest you call `head` first to get the header information. Then do the `get` as well.

(Updated - the first chunk holds the beginning of the *content* so this won't work.)

Comment: I don't want to do that as it means 2 HTTP requests, which will probably negate the performance boost I'm trying to gain with pass-thru chunking in the first place. I know that the headers have already been received by HTTPClient (according to HTTP protocol), I guess I just can't access them due to HTTPClient API limitations (unless I've missed something).

Comment: @WilliamDenniss: Fair enough. I didn't think it was that great an answer myself! I've been looking at the source of `HTTPClient` and I think I have found what you want. Take a look at my update.

Comment: @Bordin, thanks for the great answer, it's good to have a working example of `get_async`. However, it does not work with binary requests! Replace the url in your answer with `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Wikipedia-logo.png` and it will hang (ruby 2.0.0, httpclient 2.3.4.1). Can you think of any reason for that, or is it an API bug? I have assumed the latter and logged it here: https://github.com/nahi/httpclient/issues/173

Comment: btw. one optimisation is to switch the `read` to `readpartial` (and add a `rescue EOFError`), as this will more closely match the input stream (effectively reading whatever data it has).

Comment: @WilliamDenniss: I can't say why, but this works fine if you use `sysread` instead of `readpartial` :)

Comment: @WilliamDenniss: Actually, the `readpartial` version works as well on my system so I've proven nothing. The chunk sizes are very different between the two methods though. Maybe you need to update your gem?

Comment: You're right. It does work through `irb`. When I run it through `rails c` (Rails4), the image request hangs. Maybe it's a rails issue?  My HTTPClient gem is up to date.

Comment: You've lost me now as I know nothing of Rails at all. I'm running through the RubyMine IDE. It's probably worth running the script directly through the `ruby` interpreter on the command line, but it's my guess it will work fine. Where does it lock up under Rails? Is it the `conn.pop` that hangs, or the pipe read?

Comment: `pipe.read`. Not sure why the `rails console` is different to `irb`. Seems like your code & the gem are working fine though! I'll do some digging.